# Exchange certificate not accepted in intranet

Tags: exchange-2010, ssl-certificate

I bought a SSL certificate for Exchange OWA, I installed this cert in Exchange and it works properly with internet access... however now i get some trouble with intranet access by Outlook, i always get a certificate advice about "The name of the certificate is not valid or doesn't match..".
Can you tell me with?

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing OWA via another host name than from the internet.

The certificate has the host name inside and if the hostname and the name of the certificate do not match the given error message is printed.

Comment: My trouble is for Outlook client access not intranet owa... But how can i solve? May I need to add another certificate for local net?

Comment: It is possible to supply an alternate name to a certificate which could be used for the intranet server name. If this does not work you need to get a second certificate. But I cannot tell you how to set it up (no experience with OWA).

Comment: There are specific certificates you can buy that make use of the subject alternative name field embedded inside the cert. You buy a certificate with common name "x.y.z" and list additional alternate names like "a.b.c", "d.e.f", etc. They usually contain the term "Unified Communications" or "UCC" in the product name and most Certificate Authorities sell them.